# Windows Phone 8 - PriorityBinding

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

**I searched the documentation but apparently there is no PriorityBinding for Windows Phone 8. Is there a similar way to achieve the same behaviour in XAML in Windows Phone 8?**

I've created a Style for a ListItem:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListItem">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" />

        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
            Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />

        <Image 
            Grid.Column="2"
            Source="/images/arrow_right.png" />

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I want to add a PriorityBinding, so if the ImageSource or Text are empty I want to add placeholders.

I found this example for WPF:

```xml
<Image.Source>
    <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="/images/default_category.png">
        <Binding Path="ImageSource"/>
    </PriorityBinding>
</Image.Source>

[...]

<TextBlock.Text>
    <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="Placeholder Text">
        <Binding Path="Text"/>
    </PriorityBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

I tried to add PriorityBinding to my ImageSource in the App.xaml and the following error occurs:

```xml
The type 'PriorityBinding' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

**Edit**

I want to bind the ImageSource to the ImageSource property of my model, and if there is no data, then I want to use a placeholder as image instead of the (empty) ImageSource of my model.

The same goes for my TextBlock, if the text in my model is empty I want to display a placeholder text (e.g. "no data").

Comment: you don't need this propterty for bind image :) Just create string property and :
<textblock text="{Binding text, mode=twoway}" />
<image source="{Binding ImageUri}" />

Edit : What do you want to do? i think i don't understand sorry :$

Comment: @MatDevWp8 I edited my post, hope it helps ;)

Comment: you could implement the `PriorityBinding` class yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hoo ok i think you need to use converter, if i understand ^^

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Converter:TextConverter x:Key="TextConverter"></Converter:TextConverter>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
 <TextBlock 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
            Text="{Binding Path=Text,converter{StaticRessource TextConverter}" />

public class TextConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                return "No data";
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for fast answer, I'll try it out (propably on monday, I'm currently working on some other stuff) and if it is what I need, I'll mark it as answered ;)

Comment: 'if (value == null)
            {
                return "No data";
            }'

Comment: I think I'll have to look further into the Converter documentation to understand them, right now i have simply added propoerties to my class, which converts the text (if the text is empty return "no data"). But I have a problem with `ImageSource`s - I want to get an image from an server and while this image isn't displayed I want to display a placeholder image.

Comment: Bind your text on ImageSource too and use converter again. Check if value is null and return null or "Placeholder Text" no?

Comment: The text of the ImageSource isn't null or empty, but it will fail to load the image, because it dosen't exist on the server - so i can't use an converter. I have seen PriorityBinding for this case: first, load the placeholder, second load the real image (and as far as i understand: don't show the real image if something goes wrong - e.g. 404, source is null or empty).